# Linux - Giving all users access to a folder (and all folders and files below)

Tags: linux

I know this seems like its a question I could just google, but I've tried and to be honest I'm still stuck.

The question I'm trying to solve asks...

> Your current directory is sample_dir. Add the permission (using
>   symbolic) for gen_ed so that all users can access the file cars2:

The path is stenton/gen_ed/cars2 from the working directory.

So naturally, I assumed it was:

`chmod -R ugo+r stenton/gen_ed`, however that fails. I've tried a ton of iterations on the same line of thinking, but they've all failed.

Can someone please end this torment!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking -- perhaps you can provide some more context, or an example showing what you're looking for? What do you mean by "fails"?

Comment: Its a simple, small question for an assignment. The program is returning 'incorrect answer'. It looks to me like its the correct answer. I'm simply wondering if I'm missing something here?

Comment: Your problem asks you to change the permissions of a single file, but you're changing the permissions of a whole directory (tree).

Comment: The question says "Add the permission (using symbolic) for gen_ed", so I assumed it was the directory itself? I've also tried just the file, it still doesn't except it.

Comment: I see the problem. Look up precisely what `rwx` mean for a directory. [This page](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/perms.html) looks like it should be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it was useful. However I've tried literally every iteration of ugo+(rwx). rx isn't accepted. I have a feeling this assignment has a pass/fail answer key, (not checking output) which makes it all the more toublesome.

Comment: rx is correct. Try submitting without the recursive flag. You could also try `a` instead of `ugo`.

Comment: My friends and I have tried everything at this point. I think its time to just send the prof an email... Thanks for your help, and the page, which was very informative.

Answer (score 3):

chmod go+x stenton/gen_ed 
THIS should do the job!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is still searching for the correct answer for this question, it is:

```
chmod a+x stenton/gen_ed
```

Answer (score 0):

What bit has to be set for a directory to be accessible (traversable) by all users?

For a file to be accessible, a user must be able to traverse all the directories from the root to that file. Can they?

Since it's an assignment, I won't give you the answer.

Comment: chmod -R ugo+rx stenton/gen_ed ?

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and Type

chmod ugo+rwx /home/eallen/Downloads

or

chmod 777 /home/eallen/Downloads

"/home/eallen/Downloads"  Replace it with your   directory/foldername

if you want to remove all permission then type

chmod -rwx /home/eallen/Downloads